# jquery position change on click

Tags: jquery, css

I have a logo on a [site](http://www.boltonclinics.com/#home) I want that when I will be on home page it will at the same position where it is but when I will go to another page it's position will change some towards top and on  all other pages except home page it position will be fixed so that when I will scroll the page it will be fixed at a position.

Comment: Why would you do this with jQuery? You can do this with your server-side language of choice (or if it's not dynamic within the html). Just create an additional class for the fixed position and only give it that class on those pages.

Comment: ya but as the background position will be fixed it will come on every page.But I want it will come except the home page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (document.URL == "Your Homepage Address") {
        $("#your-image-id").removeClass("class-used-for-all-pages").addClass("class-used-for-homepage");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In PHP it would be something like:

`<div class="logo" id="<?php if($page=="home")echo 'normalhome';else echo 'fixedotherpagepwn';?>">LOGO</div>`